# Why is QML deleting my C++ ListView model?

Tags: c++, ios, qt, listview, qml

Using `Qt 5.5.1` on `iOS 9` I'm trying to assign a dynamically created `QAbstractListModel` to the `model` property of a `ListView`:

```
Window {
    ListView {
        model: api.model()
        delegate: delegate
    }
    Component {
        id: delegate
        Text { text: "Test" }
    }
}
```

`api` is a `C++` object assigned to the `QML` context with `setContextProperty`. The `model` method is a `Q_INVOKABLE` which returns a `QAbstractListModel *`. This all works, my `ListView` is populated with data.

The problem is when I start scrolling. Usually after the second full scroll (to the bottom, back up to the top and down again) my `ListView` starts to clear itself out. The debugger is telling me the `QAbstractListModel` is being destroyed.

I don't want to set `CppOwnership` on the model. Is there another way to prevent the `ListView` from destroying its model?

Comment: Does this happen on all platforms or just iOS?

Comment: I haven't tested other platforms.

Comment: Please, post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As you described it, it looks like an XY-problem and it's difficult to help you this way.

Comment: You can try to pass it via `Q_PROPERTY`, in that case ownership should be set to cpp by default...the thing is `CppOwnership` (automatic of set by you) is the best way to handle the stuff here. You can then correctly dispose the model from your `api` destructor, once the application enter closing state.

Comment: The problem is the models are dynamic. They are created as needed, and ideally would then be disposed when the view using them is changed. It looks like I'll need to build some custom lifetime management code I hadn't planned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I've accepted `ddriver`'s answer I've found a solution that seems to better match what I wanted.

By dynamically loading my components and storing the model as a variable, I'm able to get `QML` to keep my `C++` models alive and to destroy them when required, for example:

```
MyComponent {
    property var model: api.createModel()

    ListView {
        model: model
        delegate: delegate
        [...]
    }

    Component { id: delegate [...] }

    Component.onDestruction: model.destroy()
}
```

Unfortunately the `model.destroy()` call seems to be required. I was expecting the garbage collector to pick this up, but it doesn't seem to.

I've only tested this is toy examples so far, caveat lector.

Answer (score 5):

QML seems kind of broken in this regard, I've experienced completely arbitrary deletions of objects still in use in multiple scenarios. Objects with parents and referenced by the JS engine are being deleted for no apparent reason while JS garbage still takes hundreds of megabytes of memory instead of being freed. This applies to both objects returned from C++ and objects created in QML. When an object is returned from a C++ function to QML, ownership is passed to the QML engine, which makes the object vulnerable to such arbitrary deletions.

The solution is to force CPP ownership and manage the object's lifetime manually - keep in mind `destroy()` won't work on such objects, so you have to use a C++ function from QML to delete it.

```
qmlEngine.setObjectOwnership(obj, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
```

Also, as BaCaRoZzo mentioned, exposing the model as a property to api might be the appropriate form. It depends on whether the function is just an accessor to an existing object or it creates the object itself.

At any rate, keep in mind that QML object lifetime management at this point cannot and should not be trusted.

Comment: The QML engine does not take ownership of a QObject instance which already has a parent. cf: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership

Answer (score 1):

Just to say - I can confirm the same issue on both Linux x86_64 and Android ARMv7.

```
MyComponent {
    property var model: api.createModel()

    ListView {
        model: model
        delegate: delegate
        [...]
    }

    Component { id: delegate [...] }
}
```

Seems to be enough if you don't mind the model being destroyed later in time.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something to ddriver's answer, which is more than a comment.

This same problem came up for me. basically, i wanted to create a dynamic list view model (QAbstractListModel, in fact). The usual way is to put your models up front in main (or somewhere) like this:

```
QQmlContext* ctxt = engine.rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel",  &model);
```

I have one model *per* object in this case, so i needed a dynamic solution.

I have a `QObject` which creates my model for a list. The model created derives from `QAbstractListModel`. The model is created and given out by my `QObject` host with a `Q_INVOKABLE`.

First problem is that the type of the model so generated is not known and must be registered. The usual `qmlRegisterType` does not work because QAbstractListModels cannot be copied. so you must register with `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`.

That's the first bit. Now the model works *BUT* who destroys it?

Turns out both my C++ code *and* QML both try to destroy the object since ownership was implicitly given to QML as part of the `Q_INVOKABLE` accessor.

*BUT* just letting QML clean up was bad. I tracked when this happened and it didn't happen at all in a timely manner. Basically it wouldn't clean up unless I did quite radial things like resize the window. presumably, it would *eventually* clean up (garbage etc.) but i really wanted these dynamic models to be cleaned up when their host `QObject` goes out.

So ddriver's idea is the way. but also remember to register with `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`.

eg,

```
inline MyModel* MyHostObject::getModel()
{
   if (!_model)
   {
     _model = new MyModel(this);

    // retain ownership of this object.
    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(_model, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
   }
return _model;
```

}